# create list of specific dates by variabels

Tags: pandas, datetime

i am looking for a solution to create, based on a existing dataframe with a datetimeindex, a list of specific dates. these dates are based on the variables "month" and "date_d" and the start and end of the existing dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df_date = pd.date_range(start="2018-07-01",end="2020-02-02")

month = 6
date_d = 15


#expected_output_list = ['2018-12-15', '2019-06-15', '2019-12-15']
```

i expect a list of dates, starting with 2018-12-15, not 2018-06-15, because the "minimum Date" is 2018-07-01. etc.

Thanks for ideas and solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `df_date` could be filtered to match only where `% month` is 0 and the `day` matches `date_d`:

```
import pandas as pd

df_date = pd.date_range(start="2018-07-01", end="2020-02-02")

month = 6
date_d = 15

out = (
    df_date[(df_date.month % month == 0) & (df_date.day == date_d)]
        .date.astype(str).tolist()
)
```

`out`:

```
['2018-12-15', '2019-06-15', '2019-12-15']
```